# How to evaluate this integral containing trigonometric functions?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin(2x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos x\right)}{2x-\pi}dx$$

How to evaluate this integral? Please give me some hints so that I can complete it myself. No complete answers please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Substitute $x\mapsto x+\pi/2$:
$$
\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin(2x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(x)\right)}{2x-\pi}\mathrm{d}x
=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{(x+\pi/2)\sin(2x)\sin\left(\frac\pi2\sin(x)\right)}{2x}\mathrm{d}x
$$
Now consider even and odd parts and write $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$.